# Real-Time video stabilization OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing, image-stabilization

I've searched a function in OpenCV (cv::videostab), that would allow me to do video stabilization in Real-Time. But as I understand in OpenCV this is not yet available. So TwoPassStabilizer(OnePassStabilizer) require a whole video at once and not two consecutive frames.

```
Ptr<VideoFileSource> source = makePtr<VideoFileSource>(inputPath); //it's whole video
TwoPassStabilizer *twopassStabilizer = new TwoPassStabilizer();
twoPassStabilizer->setFrameSource(source);
```

So I have to do this without the OpenCV video stabilization class. This is true?

Answer (score 4):

*OpenCV library does not provide exclusive code/module for real-time video stabilization.*

Being said that, If you're using python code then you can use my powerful & threaded [**VidGear**](https://github.com/abhiTronix/vidgear) Video Processing python library that now provides real-time Video Stabilization with minimalistic latency and at the expense of little to no additional computational power requirement with [Stabilizer Class](https://github.com/abhiTronix/vidgear/wiki/Stabilizer-Class). Here's a basic usage example for your convenience:

```
# import libraries
from vidgear.gears import VideoGear
from vidgear.gears import WriteGear
import cv2

stream = VideoGear(source=0, stabilize = True).start() # To open any valid video stream(for e.g device at 0 index)

# infinite loop
while True:

    frame = stream.read()
    # read stabilized frames

    # check if frame is None
    if frame is None:
        #if True break the infinite loop
        break

    # do something with stabilized frame here

    cv2.imshow("Stabilized Frame", frame)
    # Show output window

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    # check for 'q' key-press
    if key == ord("q"):
        #if 'q' key-pressed break out
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
# close output window

stream.stop()
# safely close video stream
```

More advanced usage can be found here: https://github.com/abhiTronix/vidgear/wiki/Real-time-Video-Stabilization#real-time-video-stabilization-with-vidgear

Answer (score 0):

We created a module for video stabilization by fixing a coordinate system. It's open-source.
https://github.com/RnD-Oxagile/EvenVizion

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.